# Javascript parameter with Array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function, parameters

```js
    var show=[
    "p1",
    "p2",
    "p3"
    ];
    var n;
    function show(n){
        for(n=1;n<=3;++n){
  
   
    document.getElementById("show").innerHTML=show[n];
        }
    }
```

```html
<button onclick="show(1)">b1</button>
    <button onclick="show(2)">b2</button>
    <button onclick="show(3)">b3</button>
        
    <p id="show"></p>
```

I am trying to print p1,p2,p3 when I click b1,b2,b3 respectively. How can I do it.

Comment: Rename the array, it overrides the function with the same name. Also, arrays have zero-based indexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has several problems.

First, do not name your variable and the function with the same name. In this example, you can rename the array as `showArr`.

Then you need to remove `for` loop (it is against what you are trying to achieve). And you need to pass `index - 1` when getting the array item with index.

And there is no need for a variable `n` in the global scope (it is redundant).

```js
var showArr = [
  "p1",
  "p2",
  "p3"
];

function show(n) {
  document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = showArr[n - 1];
}
```

```html
<button onclick="show(1)">b1</button>
<button onclick="show(2)">b2</button>
<button onclick="show(3)">b3</button>

<p id="show"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use the same name `show` for the variable and the function:

```js
var show = [
  "p1",
  "p2",
  "p3"
];

function showIt(n) {
  document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = show[n - 1];
}
```

```html
<button onclick="showIt(1)">b1</button>
<button onclick="showIt(2)">b2</button>
<button onclick="showIt(3)">b3</button>

<p id="show"></p>
```